# oracle: how to use function in "ALTER" statement

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

there is a SEQUENCE named **test_seq**.

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('-'||TO_CHAR(test_seq.currval)) from DUAL;   // can work

ALTER SEQUENCE test_seq INCREMENT BY TO_NUMBER('-'||TO_CHAR(test_seq.currval)); // wrong!
```

can I use function(like: `TO_NUMBER()` or `TO_CHAR()`) in **ALTER** statement?

Answer (score 2):

[No](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_2011.htm#SQLRF00817), you cannot. The railroad diagram disallows it.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish it with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement in a block as shown.

```
DECLARE
  next_increment NUMBER := TO_NUMBER('-'||TO_CHAR(test_seq.currval));
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SEQUENCE test_seq INCREMENT BY '||next_increment;
END;
/
```

But make sure -

- you have run test_seq.nextval atleast once before you execute this
  block.
- Use the sequence increment with caution . You might get the following
  error if it goes below MINVALUE of the sequence.

  `ORA-08004:` sequence `TEST_SEQ.NEXTVAL` goes below `MINVALUE` and cannot be instantiated